# BulkWriteError exception when inserting documents with there own unique "_id" value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert some test data into a collection, the data itself contains an _id value that i have already created.

here is a small sample of the data and code that i am using when writing into the collection using the insertmany() pymongo command

```
def database_Insertions(data): #data is the list of dictionaries i am inserting
myClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myClient["Polling_Data"]
mycol = mydb["Test_Collection"]

try:
    mycol.insert_many(data)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print("Writing Error Details " ,bwe.details)
```

and heres a sample of the data i am inserting..
[data i am writing](https://pastebin.com/1Jvx0XFu)

When i attempted to run this i got a "BulkWriteError", and when i broke down the error message with a Try /Catch i got this...

```
Writing Error Details  {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'_id': 98800754}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: Polling_Data.Test_Collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: 98800754 }', 'op': {'_id': 98800754, 'Poll_Name': 'AL Daily News/Mason-Dixon', 'Date': '2020-02-04', 'Sample_Size': '625 RV', 'MoE': '4.0', 'Biden (D)': '58', 'Trump(R)': '38', 'Spread': 'Trump +20', 'State': 'Ohio'}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}
```

Most of the message isint useful except for the **"E11000 duplicate key error collection"** message embedded.
I am almost certain it has to do with the fact i am using my own custom _id value and that there is some kind of conflict with that custom _id and the one that is given by mongo as a default.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `E11000 duplicate key error collection` means that the _id value of the document you are trying to insert is already present in a document in the collection.

If you have loaded that data set before, those _id values are taken, and you'll need to either

- update/upsert the existing document instead of inserting
- remove the existing document before inserting

Comment: Removed some of the previous redundant data and the error is gone. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to insert new data with `insert_many()` method and it throws the error